# Handling special characters in password string

Tags: powershell

I have a string. Sometimes it looks like this:

> 9xABp'}H9$G(@

While, sometimes it looks like this:

> 9xABp"}H9$G(@

I do not have any control over the character set used to generate the string, but I need to have Powershell stop complaining that the string cannot be parsed and to give me all of the characters.

```
$string = '9xABp'}H9$G(@'
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $string -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

That doesn't work, so I tried wrapping my string in double quotes, instead of single quotes.

```
$string = "9xABp'}H9$G(@"
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $string -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

That's fine, but $G is not included (replaced by a backslash) and what about when my string has a double quote inside?

I tried using [Regex]::Escape().

```
$string = "9xABp'}H9$G(@"
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ([Regex]::Escape($string)) -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

But $G is still missing. Another try, this time with double and single quotes on the outside.

```
$string = "'9xABp'}H9$G(@'"
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ([Regex]::Escape($string)) -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PowerShell herestring exists for just such an occasion.

```
$string = @"
'9xABp'}H9$G(@'
"@
```

The `@"` and `"@` characters have to be on their own line, but allow for any characters inside of them.

#### Edit

Thanks to Mike Klement for reminding me of the single quote variant, which should be used if your password might contain a `$` or another character which has significance in PowerShell.

```
$string = @'
'9xABp'}H9$G(@'
'@
```

This works the same as the previous here-string but this one will not expand a variable, and is a better fit.

Comment: Yup, that seems like it'll work. I'll test it tomorrow and mark the question answered.